# How to ignore global node_modules folder when running npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I want to run a npm script (e.g., `npm run start`) but I do not want the module search path to include the global npm modules (e.g., /Users/Bob/node_modules). How can this be accomplished? Alternatively, how can I only use the locally installed modules (the modules installed in the project's root directory)?

I am imagining it would look something like this:

```bash
npm run start --local-only
```

The issue I am running into is that the npm script I am using for some reason uses global node modules which creates an error. I no longer have this error if I remove the global node_modules folder. This is not desirable as I use global npm packages outside of this project.

Comment: I have the exact same question, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Lawlzer, not yet.